# ERROR:Xst:827 - while synthesizing the code

Tags: vhdl

I 'm trying to synthesize the below code using Xlinx ISE 14.3 but I get below error.I could simulate it successfully.Please help as I'm a newbie in VHDL.

> ERROR:Xst:827 - "D:/programs_xlinx/BZFAD/DFF.vhd" line 42: Signal Q cannot be synthesized, bad synchronous description. The description style you are using to describe a synchronous element (register, memory, etc.) is not supported in the current software release.

Below is the code.

```
Entity DFF is
  Port (
    reset : in STD_LOGIC;
    clk   : in  STD_LOGIC;
    D     : in  STD_LOGIC;
    Q     : out  STD_LOGIC
  );
end DFF;

Architecture Behavioral of DFF is
begin
  process(clk,reset)
  begin
    if reset='1' then
      Q <= '0';    -- clear register
    end if;
    if (clk'event and clk='1') then Q<=D; --positive edge of clock is used
    end if;
  end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 4):

The synthesizer is confused because if `reset` is high and there is a rising edge on the clock then you have asked for two different things to happen to `Q`. You need to change the two separate `if` statements to an `if... else if ...` kind of structure.